# How to grep while excluding some words?

Tags: linux, unix, command

I wanted to grep the word "force" but most of the output listed is from the command `-force`.

When I did `grep -v "-force" filename` , it says grep : orce most probably because of the -f command.

I just want to find a `force` signal from files using grep. How?

Comment: Do you want to say you want to grep "force" but not "-force"?

Answer (score 1):

use `grep -v -- "-force"` - the double `-` signals that there are no more options being expected.

Comment: the complete answer is `grep -v -- "-force" | grep force`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grep specific word from file then we can use cat command

```
    # cat filename.txt | grep force
```

For other basic [Commands](http://www.linuxwindo.com)

Comment: cat is redundant here. simply grep the file. Google "useless use of cat" :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [-] to remove the special significance. Check this out:

```
> cat rand_file.txt
1. list items of random text
2. -force
3. look similar as the first batch
4. force
5. some random text
> grep -v "-force" rand_file.txt  
grep: orce: No such file or directory
> grep -v "[-]force" rand_file.txt | grep force
4. force
>
```

Comment: I think you need to add `| grep force` to the end of your last command as only line 4 is desirable (force signal).

Answer (score 0):

this line maybe simpler:

```
grep '[^-]force' tmp
```

it says: grep "force", but only if it does not has a prefix `-` by using `[^]`. See some simple regular expression examples [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html).